# Uinavigation bar left to right

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I have an app and i have localized the storyboard and strings .

i can't localize the navigation bar to be left to right

is there away to localize it to be the left bar button becomes in right and the right becomes left ?

Comment: what are you trying to do? make the transition animation go from left to right? then put a "back" button on the right side?

Comment: no if the app in arabic change the buttons from right to left and from left to right thats all